# SwiftUI Text field default value

Tags: view, swiftui, textfield, default, default-value

I am trying to set a default value in a text field but I don't know how.

```
//TextField("", text:$name)

struct MyView: View {

    @State var name:String = ""

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text:$name)
    }

    init(n:String) {
        name = n
    }
}
```

If I call `MyView("Jack")`, Jack does not appear as a value in the textfield.

Answer (score 10):

This can be done in a following way

```
struct MyView: View {

    @State var name: String

    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text:$name)
    }

    init(n: String) {
        _name = State(initialValue: n)
    }
}
```

Comment: @Asperi Why does undescored var name works? And is there more vanilla way of assigning initial value?

Comment: @ЭлёржонКимсанов, [Swift Property Wrappers](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0258-property-wrappers.md)

Comment: If anyone is wondering how this works, here someone actually explained this answer instead of code only: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61398097/1972372

Comment: this is interesting, any particular reason why should we use property wrappers to initialize? I mean wouldn't view updates as soon as the value is assigned in onAppear closure?(that's the whole point of @State)