# Set initial value for a TextField in SwiftUI - compare new and old value

Tags: swiftui

I have seen a lot of examples and tutorial of how to use an empty TextField for collecting new values, but none that shows how to use a TextField to edit a value.

In my use-case, I want the TextField to be prepopulated/prefilled with data from my viewmodel, then as user edits the data, a Save button should be enabled. In my form, I also have a navigationlink that leads to a sub-page where the user can select something from a list, and then be routed back to the form.

It behaves as described as long I use an empty field; the user can type something temporary in the field, navigate to the sub page, and the temp value is still like it was when he left.

```
struct TextFieldDemo: View {

    var model:String    // Actual a more complex view model
    @State var editedValue:String = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            Group{
                Text("Some label")
                TextField("Placeholder text", text: $editedValue)
            }
            Divider()
            Text("Some navigation link to push in a page where " +
                "the user can select something from a list and click back...")

            // If the user starts to edit the textfield - follows a navigation link and comes back
            // he should be able to continue edit the field where he left of - the text field should
            // not have been reset to the original value.

            Button(action: {
                // Call some save function in the ViewModel
                },label: {
                    Text("SAVE")
                }
            ).disabled(model == editedValue)
        }.onAppear(){
            // I could have done something like:
            //   self.editedValue = model
            // but it seems like this will fire if the user navigates into the described page and reset
            // the TextField to the model value.
        }
    }
}

struct TextFieldDemo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextFieldDemo(model: "The old value")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To initialize the text field with the value from your model, you need to define your own initializer and use the `State(wrappedValue:)` initializer for `@State` vars:

```swift
struct TextFieldDemo: View {

    var model:String    // Actual a more complex view model
    @State var editedValue: String

    init(model: String) {
        self.model = model
        self._editedValue = State(wrappedValue: model) // _editedValue is State<String>
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            Group{
                Text("Some label")
                TextField("Placeholder text", text: $editedValue)
            }
            Divider()
            Text("Some navigation link to push in a page where " +
                "the user can select something from a list and click back...")

            // If the user starts to edit the textfield - follows a navigation link and comes back
            // he should be able to continue edit the field where he left of - the text field should
            // not have been reset to the original value.

            Button(action: {
                // Call some save function in the ViewModel
                },label: {
                    Text("SAVE")
                }
            ).disabled(model == editedValue)
        }.onAppear(){
            // I could have done something like:
            //   self.editedValue = model
            // but it seems like this will fire if the user navigates into the described page and reset
            // the TextField to the model value.
        }
    }
}

struct TextFieldDemo_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TextFieldDemo(model: "The old value")
    }
}
```

Comment: That is some hokey crap right there. Not your explanation of it, the fact that is the only way to do it. That feels very hacked on there, Apple. What were you thinking? Underscores and wrappedValue and State wrappers. ugh.

Comment: @ChrisH you have no idea how often I feel the same way. Property wrappers, I've come around on — they're pretty cool and powerful, and you can use them in more and more contexts as new versions of Swift come out, but some parts of SwiftUI have really terrible ways to do things.

Comment: I need to show the original values that have been store on **Firebase** and allow users to change them and update on Cloud. How's it possible?

Answer (score 0):

how about something like this test code. The key is to use the "ObservableObject":

```
import SwiftUI


class MyModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var model = "model1"
}

struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var myModel = MyModel()
@State var editedValue = ""

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 20) {
            Group{
                Text("Some label")
                TextField("Placeholder text", text: Binding<String>(
                    get: { self.editedValue },
                    set: {
                        self.editedValue = $0
                        self.myModel.model = self.editedValue
                })).onAppear(perform: loadData)
            }
            Divider()

            NavigationLink(destination: Text("the nex page")) {
                Text("Click Me To Display The next View")
            }

            // If the user starts to edit the textfield - follows a navigation link and comes back
            // he should be able to continue edit the field where he left of - the text field should
            // not have been reset to the original value.

            Button(action: {
                // Call some save function in the ViewModel
                self.myModel.model = self.editedValue
            },label: {
                Text("SAVE")
            })
        }
    }.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
}

func loadData() {
    self.editedValue = myModel.model
}

}
```

Comment: I think this will behave slightly different from what I wanted, but nice tip.