# Update the data stored on Firebase by inputting new values to TextFields where there have been default values

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, backend, real-time-updates

I designed a method to show the data stored on Firebase in the textfields according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61398097/12097673). Here is my solution:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI

struct TextFieldWithDefaultValue: View {

    var model: userViewModel    // Actual a more complex view model
    var textFieldName: String
    @State var editedValue: String

    init(model: userViewModel, text: String) {
        self.model = model
        self.textFieldName = text
        switch self.textFieldName {
        case "Name": self._editedValue = State(wrappedValue: model.user.name)
        case "Bio": self._editedValue = State(wrappedValue: model.user.bio)
        case "Interest": self._editedValue = State(wrappedValue: model.user.interest)
            default: self._editedValue = State(wrappedValue: "No records")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
       TextField(textFieldName, text: $editedValue)
    }

}
```

One of its shortages is that I cannot bind the value of the input of object State. Therefore, the value on Firebase is never changed. So my question is, is there a shortcut that allows me to update the value whenever a user's input is different from the original one? Here is the rest of my code:

```
@StateObject var currentUser: userViewModel
@State private var showingAlert = false
    
    
var body: some View {
TextFieldWithDefaultValue(model: currentUser, text: "Interest")
                        .padding()
                        .keyboardType(.numberPad)
                        .background(Color.white.opacity(0.06))
                        .cornerRadius(15)

Button(action: {
                        currentUser.updatePersonalInfo()
                        self.showingAlert = true
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Save")
                            .foregroundColor(Color("Color"))
                            .fontWeight(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.bold/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                            .padding(.vertical)
                            .frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 100)
                            .clipShape(Capsule())
                    })
                    .disabled(currentUser.getName() != "" || currentUser.getInterest() != ""  || currentUser.getBio() != "" ? false : true)
                    .opacity(currentUser.getName() != "" || currentUser.getInterest() != ""  || currentUser.getBio() != "" ?  1 : 0.5)
                    .alert(isPresented: $showingAlert) {
                        () -> Alert in
                        Alert(title: Text("Congratulations!"), message: Text("Saved successfully!"), dismissButton: .default(Text("OK")))
                            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to set the StateObject variable, which I pass to the TextField with the actual value in `init()` function in the View.

```
@StateObject var currentUser: userViewModel

init(currentUser: userViewModel) {
        self._currentUser = StateObject(wrappedValue: currentUser)
}

TextField("Name", text: $currentUser.user.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onChange` modifier to track changes of the text and propagate it to view model like this

```
TextField(textFieldName, text: $editedValue)
    .onChange(of: editedValue) { newValue in
        viewModel.saveToFirebase(newValue)
    }
```

The other thing you could do is make your view model an`ObservableObject` and add `editedValue` there as a `@Published` property. Then from the `View` you do this:

```
struct TextFieldWithDefaultValue: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: UserViewModel

    var body: some View {
        TextField(textFieldName, text: viewModel.$editedValue)
    }
}
```

and inside the view model you can use Combine to subscribe to value’s changes and save data like this:

```
class UserViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var editedValue = “”

    init(…) {
        // Init `editedValue` here

        $editedValue
            .sink { // Save data here }
            .store(in: …)
    }
}
```

The only other thing you might want to think about is that you probably don’t want to update value on Firebase every time a single character changes. But this is already out of scope of this question